# Deleted snapshot- any options for recovery?

Tags: hyper-v

I have deleted a .avhdx file stupidly due to disk space issues, and lack of knowledge of VM's. Obviously when I try to start to start the virtual machine, it wont start because the file is missing.

Are their any options here to recover or am I royally screwed? 
How do I run getdataback on a Hyper 2012 install without a GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Was that snapshot created recently? If so, you could try creating a new VM in Hyper-V that uses the original .vhdx file as the disk.  Theoretically, you should still have all your original data in that file, you would just lose all the changes made after the snapshot.  Either way, lesson learned.

Comment: Lesson learnt for sure. I have a backup from 3 weeks ago- no issues there. But ideally, as anyone would, todays ***backup*** would be great. Can getdataback work on a gui'less server? The actual vhd is fine... i can mount is without issue and see data... from 3 weeks ago :. Murphys law still stands still- was going to get around to setting up a backup scheme- never got around to it!

Comment: I'd suggest you always follow 3-2-1 backup rule, with at least daily backups -
http://www.vmwareblog.org/3-2-1-backup-rule-data-will-always-survive/